# having issues with installing perl modules :: Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible

Tags: apache, perl, makefile

good day - i am still having issues with installing perl modules 
there seems to be issues with the make-file. i am trying to figure out what goes wrong here on my notebook.

```
cpan[1]> install  Data::Dumper
Running install for module 'Data::Dumper'
Running make for S/SM/SMUELLER/Data-Dumper-2.161.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://mirrors.hostingromania.ro/cpan.org/authors/id/S/SM/SMUELLER/Data-Dumper-2.161.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://mirrors.hostingromania.ro/cpan.org/authors/id/S/SM/SMUELLER/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for /home/martin/.cpan/sources/authors/id/S/SM/SMUELLER/Data-Dumper-2.161.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Building S/SM/SMUELLER/Data-Dumper-2.161.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Data::Dumper
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp Dumper.pm blib/lib/Data/Dumper.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for Dumper ()
chmod 644 "Dumper.bs"
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Dumper.bs blib/arch/auto/Data/Dumper/Dumper.bs 644
"/usr/bin/perl" "/usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '/usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/ExtUtils/typemap'  Dumper.xs > Dumper.xsc
mv Dumper.xsc Dumper.c
cc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g -Wall -pipe   -DVERSION=\"2.161\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.161\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"  -DUSE_PPPORT_H Dumper.c
/bin/sh: cc: Kommando nicht gefunden.
Makefile:332: recipe for target 'Dumper.o' failed
make: *** [Dumper.o] Error 127
  SMUELLER/Data-Dumper-2.161.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Failed during this command:
 SMUELLER/Data-Dumper-2.161.tar.gz            : make NO

cpan[2]>
```

well - i need to make sure that the make is set propperly ..good day - i am still having issues with installing perl modules 
there seems to be issues with the make-file. i am trying to figure out what goes wrong here on my notebook.

Comment: »» cc: Kommando nicht gefunden «« : `cc` is usually a link to gcc : `/usr/bin/cc -> gcc`

Answer (score 4):

A C compiler is required to build that module, but the C compiler which perl was built with, 'cc' isn''t available. You will need to install that first.

But Data::Dumper is part of the standard perl distribution, so you shouldn't need to install it anyway. If you're using a Linux distribution where the perl installation has been split into multiple packages, then you may just need to do something like

yum install perl-Data-Dumper